# Issue with PageViewController iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a problem with UIpageviewController with Swift in iOS, this is the code:

```
class RootPageController: UIPageViewController , UIPageViewControllerDataSource , UIPageViewControllerDelegate{


     var showPhotoController: PageController! // it's the first page
     var array : NSMutableArray?
     var id : String?
     var photosActivities : NSArray? // photos that I have to show in the pages
     var index : Int?

    override func viewDidLoad() {


        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
        self.showPhotoController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("first") as PageController

        self.array = NSMutableArray()
        self.array?.addObject(self.showPhotoController)
        self.index = 0

        self.setViewControllers(self.array, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        var model = ModelDataServer(username: "", password: "")

        self.photosActivities = model.getPhotosActivityWithID(self.id!)

        self.showPhotoController.photo.image = self.photosActivities?.objectAtIndex(self.index!) as? UIImage


        self.index = self.index! + 1

    }
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {

        if(self.index > 0){

            self.index = self.index! - 1

            var previousPage =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("first") as PageController


            var image: UIImage = self.photosActivities?.objectAtIndex(self.index!) as UIImage 
            previousPage.photo.image =  image
            return previousPage
       }


        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {



        if(self.index! < self.photosActivities!.count ){

            var newPage : PageController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("first") as PageController

        var image: UIImage = self.photosActivities?.objectAtIndex(self.index!) as UIImage 
        newPage.photo.image =  image
        self.index = self.index! + 1
        return newPage

        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

.

```
PageController Class

        class PageController: UIViewController {

            @IBOutlet var photo: UIImageView! = UIImageView()

            required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
                    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
                }
        }
```

I have a PageViewController and it's composed by various pages. This pages are a view controller and it has a UIIMageView for showing an image. The type of this viewcontroller is PageController.

My problem is this:

when I change the page and go to next page I see the next PageController but I don't see the image in UIIMageView even if I , in the `viewControllerAfterViewController` , set the new image.

Thank a lot for your time

Comment: Just to understand better, what do you see in the `UIImageView` for the next page? Always the same image? Or nothing?

Comment: I see nothing . I see only the view background( it's yellow)

Comment: I see the image only in the first page ( showPhotoController in the code) , from the second onwards I see only the view background

Comment: Make sure the image you are retrieving from the array is not nil.

Comment: Yes , it's not nil because I get this ( using println()) "Optional(<UIImage: 0x7f8559dc4f90>)"

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to the fact that a view controller's views are instantiated lazily, even though the view controller itself is instantiated from a storyboard.  The result is that `previousPage.photo` and `newPage.photo` are both nil when you try to set their image.  To get round this, I would add a separate UIImage stored property to the PageController class.

```
var photoToShow : UIImage = UIImage()
```

Then in your `viewControllerBeforeViewController` and `viewControllerAfterViewController` methods, set this new property based on the relevant item from your photo array:

```
newPage.photoToShow = self.photosActivities?.objectAtIndex(self.index!) as UIImage
```

and

```
previousPage.photoToShow = self.photosActivities?.objectAtIndex(self.index!) as UIImage
```

Then in the `viewDidLoad` of the `PageController` class (at which point the view and subviews, including the `photo` UIImageView, will have been instantiated), set `photo.image` to the new stored property:

```
photo.image = photoToShow
```